# Passing Values from asp.net to a c# method - Onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to send a value to `Link_Click` (which is a method) by clicking on this link :

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="TheLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' onclick="Link_Click"></asp:HyperLink>
```

the Value is: `Eval("name")`

Comment: Where on page (inside what controls) is this link situated? And how are you retrieving the value?

Comment: inside a listview, and, for the value, here's the method Link_Click
protected void Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string strName = ""; // strName is the value I want to get from the link

            string url;

            url = "Link.aspx?name=" + strName;
            Response.Redirect(url);

        }

Comment: I believe the method needs to be public to be used on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick is a client-side javascript event handler, so you can do it this way:

```
onclick="<%= "Link_Click(" + Eval("name") + ")" %>
```

Otherwise, HyperLink navigates to another page, and you need to add the NavigateUrl property to a value like:

```
NavigateUrl="Some.aspx?name=<%# Eval("name") %>"
```

if that will work, but I think you need to do it as:

```
NavigateUrl="<%= "Some.aspx?name=" + Eval("name").ToString() %>"
```

Comment: Then please update your question to include additional information, such as how you are expecting to receive the value...  The approach I took was to grab the value via `Request.QueryString("name")`, so are  you saying it is erroring, the value is blank, or what you expected to happen isn't happening?

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `NavigateUrl='<%# "Link.aspx?name=" + (string)Eval("name") %>'`
In fact, in did work this way. So thank you very much